# Changing entry running order for mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I'm not sure how to do this or even if it's possible. I have a table of entries, but I'd like to change the running order of the entries. I've got a field called 'ID' which is set to auto-increment. I want the people in the back end to change the order of the entries themselves. So for example, if they move one entry up then the one above will automatically move down.

I've put up and down arrows by each entry, but am not sure what to do next. The code I've written is:

```
<?php
$id = $_GET['id'];
$direction = $_GET['direction'];
$menu = $_GET['menu'];

con = mysql_connect("hostname", "user", "password");
if  (!$con)
{
die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db("table", $con); 
$sql = "SELECT priority FROM Menu WHERE ID = $_GET[id]";
list($curpos) = mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));
// Find new position
if ($direction > 0)
{
// To be moved up
$sql = "SELECT priority FROM Menu WHERE priority < $curpos AND ID = $id ORDER BY priority DESC LIMIT 1";
list($newpos) = @mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));
}
else
{
// To be moved down
$sql = "SELECT priority FROM Menu WHERE priority > $curpos AND ID = $id ORDER BY priority ASC LIMIT 1";
list($newpos) = @mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));
}
if ($newpos)
{
$sql = "UPDATE Menu SET priority = $curpos WHERE priority = $newpos AND Menu = $menu";
mysql_query($sql);

$sql = "UPDATE Menu SET priority = $newpos WHERE ID = $id";
mysql_query($sql);
}
echo $msg; ?>
```

but this doesn't seem to do anything, I've seen it working in things like cPanel's but really don't know how to implement it myself.
I'd be grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not touch the ids for that. Create a new column "sorting" and use that. Changing the ID might cause problems and is not nice

Comment: Thanks, I've created a field called 'priority', but will the code now work, or do I need to change it at all?

Comment: if i see correctly you are looking for the next entry depending on the direction, get that id and switch the "priority" value of those two. If so, this should work. In your code you use two UPDATES in a row where both update ID=$id, maybe theres your problem. Try to look in your DB and do some debug to find out whats wrong. Or Edit the new code in your question

Comment: I've changed it, but still doesn't seem to work:
if ($direction > 0)
{
$sql = "SELECT priority FROM Menu WHERE priority < $curpos AND ID = $id ORDER BY priority DESC LIMIT 1";
list($newpos) = @mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));
}
else
{
$sql = "SELECT priority FROM Menu WHERE priority > $curpos AND ID = $id ORDER BY priority ASC LIMIT 1";
list($newpos) = @mysql_fetch_array(mysql_query($sql));
}
if ($newpos)
{
$sql = "UPDATE Menu SET priority = $curpos WHERE priority = $newpos AND Menu = $menu";
mysql_query($sql);
$sql = "UPDATE Menu SET priority = $newpos WHERE ID = $id";
mysql_query($sql);

Comment: put in in your question please, cant see anything here

Comment: okay I've changed the original question now so it should have the new code I've got. Thanks for helping me sort this

Comment: why is there a "Menu = $menu" in one and only one query? i think this should not be needed at all - or in more queries. And you still select ID for curpos, which makes no sense and has to be priority of course. Dont know what you have in you db exactly, but it might be good if you also select the id of the row with which you are switching prioritys and use that for the where clause in the update.

Comment: Sorry I'm quite new to this and don't quite understand what you mean. I've got the ID so that I know which entry is being effected. The curpos should now be the priority field.

Comment: SELECT ID FROM field WHERE ID = $_GET[id] will select the id for each row where the id is $_GET[id], so you get no new information from that and you do not need to do that. But you try to set priority to curpos so you need the position value of that row. Try to add some example values from your table and what happens if you call your code, my telepathic skills arent that great today :)

Comment: lol I've changed it to SELECT priority FROM Menu WHERE ID = $_GET[id] but this doesn't seem to be working - I've also 'echoed' various bits and they all seem to work, but $newpos doesn't echo anything so I'm not sure if that's where the problem might be?

Comment: depends on what should be there. If your priority columns are empty this is a problem. I would suggest initializing them with the id value for starters (update menu set priority=id) .. do some more echoes and give a sample with actual data, otherwise i can only guess what might be wrong

Comment: The priority has unique numbers in it (I set them all manually), but if I go to the file with ?direction=1&id=3&menu=Starters after it it will echo the direction as 1, id as 3, menu as Starters and curpos as 3 (which is correct), but nothing is echoed for newpos

Comment: Okay I think we might be getting somewhere. I've modified to code slightly and it now echoes $newpos as well, but it seems that this bit isn't being executed at all "if ($newpos)
  {
   $sql = "UPDATE Menu SET priority = $curpos WHERE priority = $newpos";
   mysql_query($sql);

   $sql = "UPDATE Menu SET priority = $newpos WHERE ID = $id AND priority = $curpos";
   mysql_query($sql);

   if (!mysql_error() && mysql_affected_rows()) $msg = "Dish moved";

  }"

Comment: replace "mysql_query($sql);" with "mysql_query($sql) or die(mysql_error());" this will show you errors in the updates. And i am not sure if your priority values are unique, so it would be better to update where id=... and not priority. You can get it in there queries where you fetch newpos

Comment: WOW Thank you it's now working!! I'd forgotten that I'd set the priority field to be unique!. Thank you so much for your help

Answer (score 0):

It's better to have priority field for the records to do it. It's not good to change primary key-s of records.

Comment: I've created a priority field and have changed the code, but it still doesn't seem to work :(

Answer (score 0):

If you have added the priority field, you need to change your SQL to order by priority and also to make sure the code that changes the order is updating the priority field.